# Can't create transaction: unexpected error: Call method failed

Tags: transfer, trezor, monero-core

When trying to send Monero using Trezor Model T as hardware wallet, I get the following error:

```
2021-04-21 17:52:12.637 69852   ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   Can't create transaction:  unexpected error: Call method failed
    2021-04-21 17:52:12.640 69852   WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:412   "Could not convert argument 0 at"
    2021-04-21 17:52:12.640 69852   WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:412        "onTransactionCreated@qrc:/main.qml:830"
    2021-04-21 17:52:12.640 69852   WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:412   "Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
    2021-04-21 17:52:12.640 69852   WARNING frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:412   "This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"
```

GUI Version: 0.17.2.1-8444a956 (Qt 5.15.2)
Embedded Monero version: 0.17.2.0-release

I also tried it using the CLI wallet Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release). Same error "Can't create transaction:  unexpected error: Call method failed"

I followed the Trezor guide:
https://wiki.trezor.io/Monero_(XMR)

Any idea where the problem is and what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: From the message, the problem seems to be in the GUI javascript code. v0.17.2.1 was released a few days ago, might fix it if you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround the problem I just had to close my other wallet (Exodus),  then it worked fine. Exodus has a Trezor integration and probably this blocked the Trezor device somehow.

Thanks to [debruyne](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/44/debruyne) for giving the hint!